# 3rd party header file confliction - need solution

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have to use the windows.h file in my code but it conflicts with other legacy include files on my project that I can not modify. This is in c++. How do I get around this problem, since I can not modify any of the header files in question? I thought about using a namespace but I would think you can not wrap a include in a namespace because once you instantiate you will get the same problem and I would also think it's bad practice? My team leader said to make my header file more stand alone, but eventually I still need to use the windows header in my cpp file where I define my class, so I would think that won't work in the long run.

Thanks

Comment: What are the conflicts and what part of windows.h do you need in your header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, my solution was to remove the windows.h file from the header and make everything generic, LPSTR, LPWSTR and even the HINSTANCE (made void* and cast back in cpp file). I guess the rest of my problem was just me being an idiot!

Comment: I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem on your own. Could you mark your own answer as solution then, to avoid this question being listed as not-answered?

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am new to this.